# Programmatically change a select though option event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok. No one is listening to me, so I'm going to try rephrasing the question by showing you WORKING CODE that does what I want, but not in the way that I want.

NOTE: I am not asking how to do this. I am asking more like...what's the best way...

```
// First I need the proper value
$select.find("option:selected").prop("selected", false);
$select.find("option:first").prop("selected", true);

// Now I need the event to fire
$select.trigger("change");
```

I'd like to do this in one line though...like the last line of code on this question.

Please don't tell me anything that you would expect someone that's been doing front end stuff for 10 years to know.

**ORIGINAL - DONT ANSWER BASED ON THE BELOW**

Doesn't really have to be jQuery, but I'm using it so it might as well be.

Basically, what I'd like to do is say

```
var $option = $select.find("option:first");
$option.trigger("click");
```

But that doesn't really work. I mean, it sort of does, but it doesn't seem to also fire the change event on the select...so I'm thinking I should actually be doing something more like...

```
$select.triggerEvent(new Event({
    type : "change",
    target : $option
});
```

But that can't be right.

Comment: If you want to select an option you can use `prop` method, `$option.prop("selected", true);`

Comment: Why does it have to be through option event ?

Comment: `$select.children().first().prop('selected', true);`

Comment: @adiktofsugar My answer was updated so you can fire the event.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()` to change the value of a `select` dropdown:

```
$select.val($select.find('option:first').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.attr` method

```
var $option = $select.find("option:first");
$option.attr('selected', true);
```

**OR** use the `.val()` for the select

```
var $option = $select.find("option:first").val();
$select.val($option);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the prop() jQuery method as follows :

```
$select.find('option:first').prop('selected',true);
```

This is [semantically](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/select) the right way to set an option as selected, it's also seems to be right way to [set properties in jQuery **since 1.6**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

If you are using jQuery **prior to 1.6**, you should do that instead :

```
$select.find('option:first').attr('selected',true);
```

If you need to trigger the change event on your select, you can do this :

```
$select.find('option:first').prop('selected',true);
$select.change();
```

Here is [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rayfranco/LKhnN/)

If you need to do it one line, you can extend jQuery in some ways *(not tested code)* :

```
;(function($){
    $.fn.changeToOption = function(n) {

        var option;

        option = this.find('option').eq(n);

        if (option.prop('selected',true)) {
            this.change();
        }

        return this;

    }
})(jQuery)
```

and then simply :

```
$select.changeToOption(0);
```

Comment: Hm. Weird that that works. Maybe it's because of all the added complexity that's actually going on in my use case...which is in a backbone view attaching delegated events onto the select which is wrapped in jquery widget.

Comment: @adiktofsugar why don't you trigger your own backbone events for backbone related views ? (BTW, this answers your original question)

Comment: @adiktofsugar and do "weird that that works" means that this works for you ?